# Excel: How do I concatenate each item in column to each item in another column (for each loop)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have not done any VBA scripts so if that is the only way please give some noob information.
I am trying to loop through one column and concat each value with values from another column.

Example

Column A | Column B | Column C
A                             1
B                              2
C                              3
D
E

I would like Column C to contain:
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
And so on.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741469/every-possible-combination-of-the-contents-of-2-columns-in-excel

Comment: AHHHHH!! Thank you that got me taken care of.  Not sure why I didn't see that post when searching.  Thanks!

Comment: coz it is not in superuser QnA... n 'concatenate' is not the keyword in that Q. ( :

Comment: @killbot801  you may share the answer here (at the answer tab) for the benefit of others.. ( :